# Spring Data Mongo @CreatedAt annotation not working with nested document field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot 2.4.0 along with Spring Data Mongo.

The POJO class mapped to collection is:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = {"EI_EXPOSE_REP", "EI_EXPOSE_REP2"},
  justification = "This is a bean")
@Document(collection = "Posts")
@Data
@Builder
public class Post {

@Id
private String id;
private ActorInfo actorInfo;
private String text;
private Media media;
private int likes; 
private Meta meta;
@Version
private Integer version;

@Data
@Builder
public static class Meta {
   @CreatedDate // <-- this is not working
   private Instant createdAt;
   @LastModifiedDate // <-- this is not working
   private Instant updatedAt;
   private String event; 
}
```

}

I am using MongoRepository to save above POJO in DB using save().
But I don't see the createdAt and updatedAt being populated in the collection.
This is what is being saved in collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("600fc6b23d5ebf145b7bbc0d"), "actorInfo" : { "_id" : "1", "role" : "USER" }, "text" : "Helo", "likes" : 0, "meta" : { "event" : "CREATED" }, "version" : 0, "_class" : "com.highstreet.socialmediaservice.adpater.output.type.Post" }
```

Comment: AFAIK that only works on root level documents, those with `@Document` not on nested properties/collections.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you have any reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enable the auditing? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.auditing

Comment: My understanding is I don't need to enable audit if I just want couple of auto generated timestamp field.
I am not using, for example, @createdby field.

Comment: Give it a try. If you look at that interface you can see `/*** Configures whether the creation and modification dates are set. Defaults to {@literal true}.*  * @return*/ boolean setDates() default true;`. This seem to enable the setting of dates when this interface is used

Comment: Yeah reading the interface looks like this is needed. Let me give it a try!